# How do I resolve FCM Cloud function npm errors?

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
 error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
 23:13  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
 28:13  error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
 28:13  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
 33:21  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
 45:19  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
 45 :19  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
 48:27  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  '
```

Above code is error content (terminal Mac Os), since terminal deployed, this error code shows up.

I follow firebase contents and read some time, but I don't know.

Firebase justify:

"Send messages to specific devices

To send a message to one specific device, forward the device's registration token as shown below. For more information about registration tokens, see About Client Settings by Platform."

I am using FCM push message, but only deployed, this code show
this code is showing push message to specified person's uid.

Some error distress me, and this is my code(exactly this is other person code (flutter FCM demo)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document('messages/{groupId1}/{groupId2}/{message}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
console.log('----------------start function--------------------')
const doc = snap.data()
console.log(doc)

const idFrom = doc.idFrom
const idTo = doc.idTo
const contentMessage = doc.content

// Get push token user to (receive)
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('user')
  .where('uid', '==', idTo)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(userTo => {
      console.log(`Found user to: ${userTo.data().nickname}`)
      if (userTo.data().pushToken && userTo.data().chattingWith !== idFrom) {
        // Get info user from (sent)
        admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .where('id', '==', idFrom)
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot2 => {
            querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
              console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().nickname}`)
              const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: `You have a message from "${userFrom.data().nickname}"`,
                  body: contentMessage,
                  badge: '1',
                  sound: 'default'
                }
              }
              // Let push to the target device
              admin
                .messaging()
                .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload)
                .then(response => {
                  console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log('Error sending message:', error)
                })
            })
          })
      } else {
        console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
      }
    })
  })
return null
})
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `async/await` to make the code more readable and the stacktrace  more clear. Then, please share the new stacktrace, so we can help you.

Comment: what does   'share stacktrace' mean? i First time experiencing this stack over flow.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the new error stack after refactoring your promise chain with async/await.

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about node.js.
I know a little about asynchronous systems, but I don't know node.js well.
But this is essential for the flutter app.
I'm sorry but I'd appreciate it if you could fix it.